# must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context

Tags: magento2, controllers

```
Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given
```

Banging my head over this.   I have cleared both 
 `var/di` and `var/generation`, flushed cache and then recompiled.  Same thing happens.

Same thing with this super basic controller

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Controller\Loginas;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function execute()
    {
        return "TEST";
    }
}
```

router

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
            <module name="MyNamespace_MyModule"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: What Magento version are you using?

Comment: does your class have a constructor?

Comment: version 2.1.2 .

Comment: Did you delete `var/generation` folder?

Comment: yes, I deleted var/generation as well as var/di and all other cache directories

Comment: Just recompile by using **setup:di:compile**. Your code didn't wrong.

Answer (score 2):

make you need to change your code to this:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Controller\Loginas;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
    {
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return "TEST";
    } 
}
```

After changing the code, remove the contents of var/generation/MyNamespace and then try to run again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like __construct() method is missing in your controller.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Also, your controller file should be inside appropriate folder like "Index" or "Adminhtml"

Comment: Yes, its the same with an without the default constructor.  From what I understand the constructor really isnt required unless you need something other than context but I added it anyway, cleared di and generation and regenerated.    In route I set my front controller as 'mymodule' so in this instance it would be /mycontroller/loginas due to the namespace however I tried it as Index namespace with same result.

Comment: can you put your whole module on git hub?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have injected object manager check the code, run `di:compile` comment after adding this code.

```
namespace MyModule\Service\Controller\Module;

class Version extends \MyModule\Service\Controller\Module {

    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $helper = null;
    protected $config = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \MyModule\Service\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \MyModule\Service\Helper\Data $helper,\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager

    ) {

        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->objectManager = $objectmanager;
        parent::__construct($context);
        parent::initParams();

    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $data = new \stdClass();
        $data->magentoVersion = (string) $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata')->getVersion();
        $data->phpVersion = (string) phpversion();
        $data->moduleEnabled = $this->helper->getConfig()['enabled'];
        $data->apiVersion = "2.0";
        return $result->setData($data);
    }
}
```